# No speedup when using Python multiprocessing for parallel hashing

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out why the below task, repeatedly RC4 encrypting a string, is slower when using Pool.map(). You can see that I map the long-running `attack_byte` function to range(0, 16), which is slower than iteratively calling `attack_byte` 16 times. Is there some operation in my code that can't be parallelized?

```
import binascii
import base64
import itertools as it
import operator as op
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4

secret_cookie = base64.b64decode("QkUgU1VSRSBUTyBEUklOSyBZT1VSIE9WQUxUSU5F").decode("utf-8")

def rc4_oracle(request):
    rand_key = os.urandom(128)
    cipher = ARC4.new(rand_key)
    ptext = request + secret_cookie

    return cipher.encrypt(ptext)

def attack_byte(idx):

    chars = {char: 0 for char in range(256)}

    padding = 'A'*(15 - idx)

    for i in range(2**24):
        if i % (10**6) == 0:
            print("Iteration: ", i)

        ctext = rc4_oracle(padding)
        guess = ctext[15] ^ 0xF0
        chars[guess]+= 1

    max_char = max(chars.items(), key = op.itemgetter(1))
    return chr(max_char[0])

pool = mp.Pool(processes = 16)
found_cookie = pool.map(attack_byte, range(0, 16))

#for i in range(16):
    #found_cookie += attack_byte(i)
```

Note: This is from the cryptopals crypto challenges.

I am using a VSphere VM with 24 cores and 64GB of RAM.

Comment: Please include all the relevant imports in your code. It should be reproducible (it's currently not). Also, please include information on your hardware setup, and the various timings you are observing for each task.

Comment: Resolved; I discovered that os.urandom is blocking, preventing any speedup from parallelizing.